# sql count unique values from specific field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
|from| to | 
|  7 |  9 |
|  7 |  9 |
|  3 |  9 |
|  3 |  2 |
```

Lets say I'm user 9 and want to find out how many user have wrote to me.
With the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE to = 9;
```

I get 3 which means I got 3 new messages, but how to find out ho many users wrote me which would be 2 in this case?

Comment: Note that you have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course.

Comment: Yes I got one but it wouldn't help to write it here ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `from`)
FROM tab
WHERE `to` = 9;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more detailed result, you can use `GROUP BY`.

This way make it possible to see how many times the `from` user have sent messages to `to` user.

E.g.

```
SELECT from, to, count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY from, to
```

This will return:

```
|from  |to  |count(*) |
|------|----|---------|
|7     |9   |2        |
|3     |9   |1        |
|3     |2   |1        |
```

You can even insert your restriction, if you want:

```
SELECT from, to, count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY from, to
HAVING to = 9
```

That would result in:

```
|from  |to  |count(*) |
|------|----|---------|
|7     |9   |2        |
```

Just an extra way to do it.